Tail bound for gaussian on lattice
Suppose I have a Gaussian distribution
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-x^2/2 \sigma^2}$$
If the gaussian is continuous, then we can retrieve a Chernoff-like bound:
$$\int_t^\infty f(x) dx \le e^{-t^2/2\sigma^2}$$
Now suppose we discretize the Gaussian, where $k$ is a discrete value:
$$\bar{f}(k) = \frac{f(k)}{\sum_k f(k)}$$
is it possible to derive a tail bound for this distribution?
